# Custom UITableViewCell with nib and Auto Layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I’m getting pretty sick of Auto Layout with `UITableView` now…

Apple’s docs and code demos all seem to work for them, but when I try it I get no luck. I’ve even deleted and rebuilt nibs from scratch just to see if I’ve set properties inadvertently… Twice.

Trouble is, this time round I’ve got Auto Layout cells working, woo? No. They only resize when scrolled out of the viewport and back in. (I’m guessing by a reload of some kind).

Has anyone come across this issue? There’s a few questions similar to it on SO but no fixes, just discussions of how it must be a bug.

Here is my code:

Called on the `UITableView`’s `IBOutlet` `didSet` method:

```
private func loadHeadlinesTableView()
{
    headlinesTableView.delegate = self
    headlinesTableView.dataSource = self

    //  Register classes/nibs

    headlinesTableView.registerClass(HeadlineHeroTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.HeroHeadline)
    headlinesTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "HeadlineHeroTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.HeroHeadline)

    headlinesTableView.registerClass(HeadlineBigTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.BigHeadline)
    headlinesTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "HeadlineBigTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.BigHeadline)

    headlinesTableView.registerClass(HeadlineMediumTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.MediumHeadline)
    headlinesTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "HeadlineMediumTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.MediumHeadline)

    headlinesTableView.registerClass(HeadlineSmallTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.SmallHeadline)
    headlinesTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "HeadlineSmallTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifiers.SmallHeadline)

    //  Automatic cell height

    headlinesTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    headlinesTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 128

    headlinesTableView.backgroundView = nil
    headlinesTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if tableView.isEqual(headlinesTableView)
    {
        //  Headlines

        var cell: HeadlineTableViewCell!

        switch indexPath.section
        {
        case HeadlineSections.Index.HeroHeadlines:

            //  Hero

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifiers.HeroHeadline, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? HeadlineHeroTableViewCell

        case HeadlineSections.Index.BigHeadlines:

            //  Big

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifiers.BigHeadline, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? HeadlineBigTableViewCell

        case HeadlineSections.Index.MediumHeadlines:

            //  Medium

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifiers.MediumHeadline, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? HeadlineMediumTableViewCell

        case HeadlineSections.Index.SmallHeadlines:

            //  Small

            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifiers.SmallHeadline, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? HeadlineSmallTableViewCell

        default:
            break
        }

        //  Return cell

        return cell
    }

    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

willDisplayCell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if tableView.isEqual(headlinesTableView)
    {
        //  Headlines

        let headlineCell = cell as! HeadlineTableViewCell
        let headline = headlineForIndexPath(indexPath)

        headlineCell.configureWithHeadline(headline)

        if let thumbnailURL = headline.thumbnailURL
        {
            headlineImageForURL(thumbnailURL, completionHandler: { (thumbnail) -> () in

                headlineCell.configureWithThumbnail(thumbnail)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

didEndDisplayingCell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if tableView.isEqual(headlinesTableView)
    {
        //  Headlines

        let headline = headlineForIndexPath(indexPath)

        if let cacheKey = headline.thumbnailURL?.absoluteString, let downloader = headlineImagesDownloading[cacheKey]
        {
            downloader.cancelRetreivingThumbnailImage()

            headlineImagesDownloading.removeValueForKey(cacheKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Custom cell class:

```
class HeadlineTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    //  MARK: - Properties

    //  MARK: Outlets

    @IBOutlet private weak var headlineImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet private weak var headlineTitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet private weak var headlineDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    //  MARK: - View Lifecycle

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // Initialization code
    }

    //  MARK: - Methods

    func configureWithHeadline(headline: Headline?)
    {
        headlineTitleLabel?.text = headline?.title
        headlineDescriptionLabel?.text = headline?.paragraph
    }

    func configureWithThumbnail(thumbnail: UIImage?)
    {
        headlineImageView?.image = thumbnail
    }
}
```

Here’s some screenshots of my custom cell nib. It was more advanced but now I’m struggling with just a label…

[image]

[image]

[image]

I know it’s a lot but I really have no idea where I could be going wrong here… Thanks

Comment: Try implementing the method for row height instead. I found it only worked for me with the method. Not setting the property row height.

Comment: But isn’t this against what’s supposed to be possible? Surely there’s an Auto Layout only solution that doesn’t involve manual height calculations?

Comment: I didn't say manually calculate height. :-) just return the automatic dimension value.

Comment: I have a blog somewhere. One sec...

Comment: Last part of this... http://www.oliverfoggin.com/using-a-static-uitableview-as-a-layout-device/

Comment: @Fogmeister implement `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and return UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Comment: Yup. For some reason that worked for me but setting the property didn't.

Comment: @Fogmeister Just to clarify, is this as well as or instead of setting the property?

Comment: I don't set the property. It may work with both. Not sure.

Comment: @Fogmeister I’ve just tried all variants and none of them work for me?

Comment: @Fogmeister In fact Apple’s docs for `rowHeight` property in `UITableView` state that `Note that if you create a self-sizing cell in Interface Builder, the default row height is changed to the value set in Interface Builder. To get the expected self-sizing behavior for a cell that you create in Interface Builder, you must explicitly set rowHeight equal to UITableViewAutomaticDimension in your code.`

Comment: Ah ok. Hmm. Well on my phone at the mo so hard to tell what else. Will take a look later. M

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help so far

Comment: @Fogmeister I managed to figure it out, see answer for details.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so after a ton of work and nearly having to buy AppleCare before “accidentally” dropping my Mac against a wall, it seems any calls to `tableView(_:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)` whereby you might affect the contents of a cell, i.e like my cell configuration methods, disrupts Auto Layout.

I’m sure I read somewhere that `tableView(_:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)` is supposed to be used for cell configuration but a closer look at Apple Docs says:

> A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color. After the delegate returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame properties, and then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.

“Customise the cell *object* before it is displayed”, not its contents.

Annoyingly there’s a little confusion as `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` doesn’t say you should customise the contents in that method:

> The returned UITableViewCell object is frequently one that the application reuses for performance reasons. You should fetch a previously created cell object that is marked for reuse by sending a dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: message to tableView. Various attributes of a table cell are set automatically based on whether the cell is a separator and on information the data source provides, such as for accessory views and editing controls.

In the words of Dumbledore, "well that was fun."

Comment: Ah man. You know I thought it was odd that you were setting contents in will display cell. But didn't think it would have that effect.